# Who am I when ssh connected to another computer

Tags: ssh, amazon-ec2, https, cygwin

In cygwin, I connect via ssh into an ec2 computer,

```
 ssh -i xxxxxxx.pem ec2-user@ec2xxxxx.amazonaws.com
```

Ask who am I and get ec2-user

```
[ec2-user@ip-xxxxxxx]$ whoami
ec2-user
```

But when I run `git clone` with https, it asks me for my 'personal' password. So that for the user of my local computer, not the one at ec2.

```
Password for 'https://localuser@bitbucket.org'
```

What's going on? Why doesn't it use ec2-user? Isn't ssh supposed to handle only communication between my local and that remote computer?

Comment: Please show your git clone command.

Comment: @Will: Man, I'm an idiot

Comment: Nah, it's a good question :) It's easy to overlook as you'd kindof expect to SSH to BitBucket as your BitBucket username or something.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It looks like you're using bitbucket. When you clone via BitBucket over SSH, use:

```
git clone git@bitbucket.org:<you>/<repository>.git
```

It looks like you're a) cloning over HTTPS rather than SSH, and, b) you're not specifying a username.

Before this will work, you'll need to generate an SSH key:

```
ssh-keygen -t rsa
```

And then copy the contents of `~/.ssh.id_rsa.pub` to your clipboard, and then paste it into the BitBucket settings for your user account, under **Account Settings** -> **SSH Keys**. The user for SSH cloning from BitBucket will always be `git`, rather than your local username or `ec2-user`.

See [here](https://confluence.atlassian.com/bitbucket/add-an-ssh-key-to-an-account-302811853.html) for more info.

Comment: Yes, missed that part